# Postgres string_agg function not recognized as aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to run this query

```
SELECT  u.*, string_agg(CAST(uar.roleid AS VARCHAR(100)), ',') AS roleids, string_agg(CAST(r.role AS VARCHAR(100)), ',') AS systemroles
FROM idpro.users AS u 
INNER JOIN  idpro.userapplicationroles AS uar ON u.id = uar.userid 
INNER JOIN  idpro.roles AS r ON r.id = uar.roleid 
GROUP BY u.id, uar.applicationid
HAVING u.organizationid = '77777777-f892-4f4a-8328-c31df32bd6ba'
    AND uar.applicationid = 'd88fbf05-c048-4697-8bf3-036f39897183'
    AND (u.statusid = '7f9f0b75-44b7-4216-bf2a-03abc47dcff8') 
    AND uar.roleid IN ('cc9ada1c-fa21-400b-be98-c563ebb65a9c','de087148-4788-43da-89e2-dd7dff097735');
```

However, I'm getting an error stating that

```
ERROR:  column "uar.roleid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 9:  AND uar.roleid IN ('cc9ada1c-fa21-400b-be98-c563ebb65a9c','...
```

string_agg() IS an aggregate function, is it not? My intent, if it isn't obvious, is to return each user record with the roleids and rolenames in comma-delimited lists. If I am doing everything wrong, could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filtering the data, so a `WHERE` clause would be needed. This [tutorial](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-where-and-having-clauses/) is worth reading.

```
SELECT  u.*, 
        string_agg(CAST(uar.roleid AS VARCHAR(100)), ',') AS roleids,
        string_agg(CAST(r.role AS VARCHAR(100)), ',') AS systemroles
FROM idpro.users AS u 
INNER JOIN  idpro.userapplicationroles AS uar ON u.id = uar.userid 
INNER JOIN  idpro.roles AS r ON r.id = uar.roleid 
WHERE u.organizationid = '77777777-f892-4f4a-8328-c31df32bd6ba'
    AND uar.applicationid = 'd88fbf05-c048-4697-8bf3-036f39897183'
    AND (u.statusid = '7f9f0b75-44b7-4216-bf2a-03abc47dcff8') 
    AND uar.roleid IN ('cc9ada1c-fa21-400b-be98-c563ebb65a9c','de087148-4788-43da-89e2-dd7dff097735');
GROUP BY u.id, uar.applicationid
```

The `HAVING` clause is helpful for filtering the aggregated values or the groups.

Since you are grouping by `u.id`, the table primary key you have [access to every column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158015/why-can-i-select-all-fields-when-grouping-by-primary-key-but-not-when-grouping-b) of the `u` table. You can either use a `where` clause or a `having` clause.

For `uar.applicationid`, it is part of the `group by` so you can also use either a `where` or a `having`.

`uar.roleid` is not part of the `group by` clause, so to be usable in the `having` clause, you would have to consider the aggregated value.

The following example filters out rows whose **aggregated** length is more than 10 chars.

```sql
HAVING length(string_agg(CAST(uar.roleid AS VARCHAR(100)), ',')) > 10
```

A more common usage, on numerical field, is to filter out if the number of aggregated rows is less than a threshold (`having count(*) > 2`) or a sum of some kind (`having sum(vacation_days) > 21`)